# How to save and load a NSString in a document based application?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, document

I want to create a document based application in Xcode. It's a note app. People can create their notes file. It's a basic app, because I'm trying to learn how you can save and load data in a document based application. I'm not trying to save a tableview, I'm trying to save and load the stringValue of a TextField.

So, how do you save and load a NSString in a **document based** app in Objective-C (Xcode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html)'s `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`
and `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` methods.

Here's an example of how to write to a file:

```
NSString *fileName = "myNote.txt";
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];
NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
[myString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&myError];
```

Or if you want something advanced, you can use Core Data.

Comment: What is the file path?

Comment: He doesn't accept this code: `NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];` The filename is not declared, and the property documentsDirectory is not found on object of type 'Document'.

Comment: It doesn't show any errors but when I try to save the file it doesn't do anything. The log says: `dataOfType:error: is unimplemented`. But there are no errors.

Comment: You can see if the file was written successfully, by browsing your file structure manually. Note sure about the log message. Maybe you can create a new question for this along with your full code.